# What's the most efficient way to share a queue between two python processes?

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, syslog

i'm implementing a syslog server in python. The general idea is to accept messages and forward them to a RabbitMQ queue for further processing.

So there are two parts:

- P1 the syslog listener, in charge of receiving messages
- P2 the backoffice, in charge of parsing syslog messages, check their format, integrity, sign them, and forward them to RabbitMQ

Obviously P2 does the main job and does expensive operations.

The P1 syslog listener should:

- be autonomous and robust: we want it to have maximum availability, so i don't want to rely on an external component (eg redis). It should also be able to receive messages even if P2 is offline, caching them for a while.
- have maximum performance (expected 40k messages/sec)
- answer the syslog client (when the client is using rsyslog RELP protocol, that implements an ACK)

P1 will be probably implemented using Tornado.

The P2 processer just takes messages from P1, process them and forwards them to RabbitMQ, probably using Tornado for async communication with RabbitMQ.

So I need P1 and P2 to talk to each other, in both directions.

Implementing P1 and P2 as native python threads doesn't fit: because of the python GIL, only one of them would execute as the same time. It defeats the performance objective.

Similarly, implementing P1 and P2 in the same tornado loop in the same single-threaded python process has a performance impact on P1 (as some operations in P2 can be "kinda" long and make the IOLoop busy).

So P1 and P2 probably have to be distinct unix processes.

I don't expect P2 to be available all the time, so a simple IPC would not work.

Sharing a Redis queue between P1 and P2 would have the job done, but then P1 would rely on Redis being available.

I tried to use LMDB as a shared queue, but the performance is not so great (wrong use case for LMDB: as many reads as writes, and some locking happen as P1 and P2 are different unix processes).

What would be the best way to achieve all of that ? (except "don't use python!")

Comment: Sound's like you're just looking for high performance networking between two processes.  Have you considered http://zeromq.org/ ?

Comment: the comment was a bit terse, but indeed it drove me to the right path: stop thinking about "shared storage" between processes, think message passing, and rewrite the architecture in service oriented patterns with ZeroMQ. Thanks !